# How to get an array of table names in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get the output of the query 'SHOW TABLES FROM database_name' into an array using the ActiveRecord database connection. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. can someone please enlighten me?

-C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use what ActiveRecord gives you out of the box:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DESCRIBE TABLE table_name")
```

and was told to check my SQL manual.  Doing so, I found that

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DESCRIBE table_name").each{|r| p r }
```

worked.  Put whatever actual logic you need in the block.

Comment: I was almost there, I just wasn't using the block. Thanks alot!

-C